# Actionbar back button changes when searchview expands

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I am using the `AppCompat` activity, and I have changed the color of the backbutton to white [normal searchView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CocoZ.png). My `ActionBar` has a search view, which when expanded, changes the color for the back button from white to black. [expanded searchView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwF9T.png)

I need to maintain the color of the back button of the `ActionBar` to white.
I have tried `addOnLayoutChangeListener`, but it did not help me. Please suggest a solution.

I think, there should be a way to implement the color of actionBar back button in theme itself.

EDIT:

Setting white color for actionBar back button:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getColoredArrow(context));

    public static Drawable getColoredArrow(Context context) {
        Drawable arrowDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        Drawable wrapped = DrawableCompat.wrap(arrowDrawable);

        if (arrowDrawable != null && wrapped != null) {
            // This should avoid tinting all the arrows
            arrowDrawable.mutate();
            DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapped, Color.WHITE);
        }

        return wrapped;
    }
```

search view menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:icon="@drawable/menu_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the back button image resource to the black image whatever you want to set whenever your search button is pressed and set it back to white whenever the search bar is hidden

Comment: No, that does not work, I have tried it. I think there might be a way to change the theme itself.

Comment: I have added the code, where I set the color of actionBar back button, and search view, which chnages it back to black, when expanded.

Comment: No, I have set white color for the back button, but the searchView overrides the color of back buttton when expanded. I have also linked the screenshots.